# Rails jQuery adapter rendering thrice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the Beginning Rails 3, Updated book from Apress 2010. The problem I'm having is with loading a Template dynamically with Ajax using the jQuery adapter. Everything works but it appears to be rendering three times on the page.

Here is how I dynamically load it when the user clicks the "new comment" link.

views/articles/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "new comment",
            new_article_comment_path(@article, :format => :js),
            :remote => true,
            :id => 'new_comment_link' %>
```

Then I render it as such.

views/comments/new.js.erb

```
$("<%= escape_javascript render :file => 'comments/new'," +
  " :formats => [:html], :handlers => [:erb] %>")
  .insertAfter('#comments');
```

Then I see this in the log.

```
Started GET "/articles/1/comments/new.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-18 14:51:05 -0600
Processing by CommentsController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"article_id"=>"1"}
  Article Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Rendered comments/new.html.erb (53.8ms)
  Rendered comments/new.js.erb (54.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 57ms (Views: 55.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Notice it renders my erb and the js file? Somehow that ends up with showing up three times on my page.

Any clues on how to fix this? I'm using Rails 3.2.9, rails.js (latest), and jquery-1.9.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Turns out I was adding rails.js and jquery.js TWICE!

Here is the skinny: assets/javascripts/application.js is crucial for including javascript files into your app. Basically whatever gets defined there gets pushed out to the page. You simply need to make sure that it gets defined at least once in the app as such.

views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

And that's it! The Ajax jQuery adapter should just work. Becareful not to add any additional files to the javascript folder as those will get pushed out as well and that's exactly what you don't want. Basically I was defining the adapter both through application.html.erb and manually by downloading both files. Hopefully this will help a lost poor soul somewhere along the way.

Happy Hacking.